# MD5 error for feedback_states topic

Tags: ros, md5, follow-joint-trajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I receive the following error:

> [WARN] [WallTime: 1401915353.147587]
> Could not process inbound connection:
> Client [/rostopic_4474_1401915352624]
> wants topic [/feedback_states] to have
> datatype/md5sum
> [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback/10817c60c2486ef6b33e97dcd87f4474],
> but our version has
> [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback/b11d532a92ee589417fdd76559eb1d9e]
> Dropping
> connection.{'message_definition': '#
> ====== DO NOT MODIFY! AUTOGENERATED FROM AN ACTION DEFINITION
> ======\nHeader header\nstring[] joint_names\ntrajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint
> desired\ntrajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint
> actual\ntrajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint
> error\n\n\n================================================================================\nMSG: std_msgs/Header\n# Standard metadata
> for higher-level stamped data
> types.\n# This is generally used to
> communicate timestamped data \n# in a
> particular coordinate frame.\n# \n#
> sequence ID: consecutively increasing
> ID \nuint32 seq\n#Two-integer
> timestamp that is expressed as:\n# *
> stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since
> epoch\n# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds
> since stamp_secs\n# time-handling
> sugar is provided by the client
> library\ntime stamp\n#Frame this data
> is associated with\n# 0: no frame\n#
> 1: global frame\nstring
> frame_id\n\n================================================================================\nMSG: trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint\n#
> Each trajectory point specifies either
> positions[, velocities[,
> accelerations]]\n# or positions[,
> effort] for the trajectory to be
> executed.\n# All specified values are
> in the same order as the joint names
> in JointTrajectory.msg\n\nfloat64[]
> positions\nfloat64[]
> velocities\nfloat64[]
> accelerations\nfloat64[]
> effort\nduration time_from_start\n\n',
> 'callerid':
> '/rostopic_4474_1401915352624',
> 'tcp_nodelay': '0', 'md5sum':
> '10817c60c2486ef6b33e97dcd87f4474',
> 'topic': '/feedback_states', 'type':
> 'control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback'}

I have a machine publishing on the feedback_states topic using the code shown below. The error is raised when, on another machine, i run rostopic echo "feedback_states". The publisher is Groovy whist the receiver is Hydro.

Code to publish on feedback_states:

```
b_msg = FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback()
time = rospy.Time.now()
fb_msg.header.stamp = time
fb_msg.joint_names = 'j_wrist1_arm1'
fb_msg.actual.positions = val
pub_fb_state.publish(fb_msg)
```

My initial thinking is that perhaps there is an issue with the different distributions for the control_msgs.
If this is the case or not i have no idea how to resolve this.
Should i update the Groovy version to Hydro?

Any help is appreciated it.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172797/md5-error-for-feedback_states-topic/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The publisher is Groovy whist the receiver is Hydro.

While I don't really see any changes to the `control_msgs` package between groovy and hydro (see [control_msgs/compare/groovy-devel...hydro-devel](https://github.com/ros-controls/control_msgs/compare/groovy-devel...hydro-devel)), it could well be that the MD5 of the individual messages has changed, due to changes to the code generation. That would explain the error you are seeing.

Try again with a Groovy - Groovy, or Hydro - Hydro combination and see if that resolves your error (I'm betting it will).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2014-06-13**:
Correct, the issue was that there were two different versions being used. I ended up making both Hydro and the messages worked.

Thanks for your help.